# Javascript: scope effect despite order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Please note: This is not a question about scope, per se. I understand that in order to make the code work, I should make a deep copy of the variable board rather than assigning var tboard = board. However, I am not clear why making a shallow copy has the effect I describe below.

I am experiencing something I find baffling. Basically, a global variable (board) gets altered and I have no clue how. board is initialized in the function NewGame() (which is called from select()) as an empty array. After it is initialized, nothing else is called until the user clicks a square on the board (assuming the user has selected Xs for simplicity). When that happens, the function playerMove() is called. The baffling thing is that console.log(board) at the top of playerMove() prints out an array that has an x is the clicked position and os everywhere else (ie not empty). This is bizarre because the board is empty at the end of select() (which called NewGame()) and nothing else should happen in between. To demonstrate this, I print out the function name at the top of each function and I print out the board variable in the select() function and playerMove() function to show that it changes despite nothing else being called. Please note that to get this behavior, refresh the page (otherwise the board variable starts out full of os). I think this must be somewhat an issue of scope (because I am not making a deep copy of board) but it's strange because I have no clue what is being called that is changing the variable before it gets printed out at the top of playerMove().

Here is the link to my pen and the code: http://codepen.io/joshlevy89/pen/MKjxop?editors=101

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pSym; // player's symbol
var cSym; // computer's symbol
var board;
var whosMove; // can be "player" or "computer" or "neither"
var gameOver;

setup();

$("#newgame").on('click', '#X', select);
$("#newgame").on('click', '#O', select);
$("#restart").on('click', setup);
$("table").on('click', 'td', playerMove);

function playerMove()
{
  console.log('playerMove');
  console.log(board);
  if (whosMove === "player")
  {
   var val = $(this).data('value');
   $('#g' + val).text(pSym);
   var arr = PositionToCoords(val);
   board[arr[0]][arr[1]] = pSym;
   var tboard = board;
   var gc = gameCheck(tboard);
  if (gc>=0)
  {
   endGame(gc);
   setTimeout(function(){setup();}, 1000);
   return;
  }
  whosMove = "computer";
  computerMove();


 }
 }

function computerMove() {
console.log('computerMove');
//var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
//var p2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
var tboard = board;
var pos = chooseMove(tboard);
var arr = PositionToCoords(pos);
board[arr[0]][arr[1]] = cSym;
DrawPosition(arr[0], arr[1], cSym);
var tboard = board;
var gc = gameCheck(tboard);
if (gc>=0) {
endGame(gc);
setTimeout(function(){setup();}, 1000);
return;
}
whosMove = "player";
}

function chooseMove(inboard) {
console.log('chooseMove');
// get the possible moves
var moves=[];
var scores = [];
for (var i=1;i<10;i++) {
var arr = PositionToCoords(i);
if (inboard[arr[0]][arr[1]] === undefined) {
moves.push(i);
var tboard = inboard;
tboard[arr[0]][arr[1]] = cSym;
var gc = gameCheck(tboard);
scores.push(gc);
}
}
//console.log(moves);    
//console.log(scores);
return moves[0]; // TEMPORARY
}

function endGame(gc) {
console.log('endGame');
var str;
if (gc===1) { // somebody won
if (whosMove==="player"){
str = "You Won!"
}
else {
str = "You Lost :(";
}
}
else if (gc === 0){//draw
str = "It's a draw."
}

html = '<div id="closer">' + str + '</div>';
$('#endgame').html(html);
}

function gameCheck(tboard) {
console.log('gameCheck');
// get symbol to check for
var sym;
if (whosMove === "player") {
sym = pSym;
} else {
sym = cSym;
}

// check if in a row
var hrow;
var vrow;
// check for horizonal row
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
hrow = true;
vrow = true;
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
if (tboard[i][j] !== sym) {
hrow = false;
}
if (tboard[j][i] !== sym) {
vrow = false;
}
}
if ((hrow) || (vrow)) {
return 1;
}
}

var fdrow = true;
var bdrow = true;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
if (tboard[i][i] !== sym) {
fdrow = false;
}
if (tboard[i][2 - i] !== sym) {
bdrow = false;
}
}
if ((fdrow) || (bdrow)) {
return 1;
}
// otherwise, check if board is full 
var full = true;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
var arr = PositionToCoords(i);
if (tboard[arr[0]][arr[1]] === undefined) {
full = false;
break;
}
}
if (full === true) {
  return 0;
} 
// if neither 0 (tie) or win (1), return -1 (game not over)
return -1;
}

function select() {
console.log('select');
pSym = $(this).data('value');
$('#newgame').html('');
NewGame();
console.log(board);
}

function setup() {
console.log('select');
$('#endgame').html('');
html = '<div id="opener">Xs or Os? <div id="buttons">';
html += '<div id="X" data-value="X" class="btn btn-default">Xs</div>';
html += '<div id="O" data-value="O" class="btn btn-default">Os</div>';
html += '</div></div>';
$('#newgame').html(html);
}

function NewGame() {
console.log('NewGame');
$('td').empty();

board = new Array(3);
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  board[i] = new Array(3)
};

if (pSym === "X") {
  cSym = "O";
  whosMove = "player";
} else {
  cSym = "X";
whosMove = "computer";
computerMove();
}
}

function DrawPosition(p1, p2, sym) {
console.log('DrawPosition');
var pos = p1 * 3 + (p2 + 1);
$("#g" + pos).text(sym)
}

function PositionToCoords(pos) {
console.log('PositionToCoords');
var p1 = Math.ceil(pos / 3) - 1;
var p2 = ((pos - 1) % 3);
var arr = [p1, p2];
return arr;
}
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you examining the console log after you change the object? Objects logged in the console are "live", so when you expand them you see the current value, not the value at the time it was logged.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I did not know that. I guess I have to print out each element of the multi-dimensional array then.

Comment: [joshlevy89](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5713052/joshlevy89), you can also use [`JSON.stringify(board, null, 4)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to print the object as plain text. This will capture its value at the moment of printing and save you the trouble of printing each element individually.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the break in the for loop fixes the problem.  Am I missing anything?

```
function chooseMove(inboard) {
    console.log('chooseMove');
    // get the possible moves
    var moves = [];
    var scores = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var arr = PositionToCoords(i);
        if (inboard[arr[0]][arr[1]] === undefined) {
            moves.push(i);
            var tboard = inboard;
            tboard[arr[0]][arr[1]] = cSym;
            var gc = gameCheck(tboard);
            scores.push(gc);
            break;  // <<<<<<<<<<<< This break guarantees that the computer only makes one move
        }
    }
    //console.log(moves);    
    //console.log(scores);
    return moves[0]; // TEMPORARY
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with what he sees in `console.log(board)`?

Comment: I wasn't sure what his problem was.  His game didn't work for me so I added the break and it started to.